# How to connect lift and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, scala, lift

I want to create a simple lift web application which read input throug form and insert it into database.

Comment: There are many many resources online to help with this.  If you haven't read the Lift homepage and found the resources linked there, you won't have a very good chance of producing much working code.

Answer (score 19):

You need to add mysql jdbc driver to your project (as a maven artifact, or via sbt, or just put jar in CLASSPATH) and edit properties file (props/default.props):

```
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/your_db_name
db.user=user
db.password=password
```

Also, you can setup db context in app container (Tomcat, etc.) instead. After that you can use Lift's ORM (Mapper).

Comment: while that's a noble effort, I think @Kevin's right: the OP is going to need to do a *lot* of prep work before he's even ready to ask questions.

Comment: I upvoted you because that's a fine answer, but it's a question that shouldn't been asked.  Well done for being helpful, however ^_^