# Connecting MySQl from lift app

Tags: mysql, scala, lift

I am working with lift webframe work integrated with eclipse. I have downloaded one sample app from github and i processed some forms using OnSubmit concept. now I am trying to connect my app with MySQL to store my login credentials. i have given the following code in the boot.scala configuration and i added the jdbc driver. but i don't know what went wrong. its not working. can anybody give an idea. thanx in advance.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")

def connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost/scalatest",
        "username", "pass")
```

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180040/how-to-connect-lift-and-mysql

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason of failure is somewhere in mysql.
Is it working? Is the port 3306 open?

Also, if I am not mistaken, the correct address for mysql should be something like jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scalatest
(but I may be wrong at this -- check it out.)